# create buttons based on json objects length. add a onclick attribute, but do not want it to be clicked just because page is loaded

Tags: javascript

I have a json list of objects "movieTitles", I want to populate a table with the titles and allow them to be clickable. But in the for loop going into the json I try to setAttribute("onclick", function()) to each table cell. Then when I reload the page each button is clicked instantly when I want the user to click them when they want to.

Also I realize clicking a cell may not be possible, so I have tried making buttons or links

```
document.getElementsByClassName('.programInfo').disabled = true;
```

tried disabling the buttons in the creation loop.

```
for(var x in arr){
    if(arr.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        title = arr[x].Title;
        getChannel = arr[x].Channel;
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.setAttribute("onclick",tdClick());
```

====================================================================

```
function tdClick(){
    console.log("clickedbutton");
}
```

//THIS WILL AUTO CLICK ALL THE INDIVIDUAL TITLES

Button is automatically clicked on page load instead of being an attribute that gets set to each table data cell i.e.
 `<td onclick=function()>` etc

Comment: I don't see any `JSON` !

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value should be a string.

```
 td.setAttribute('onclick', 'tdClick()');
```

Or a more modern approach is use `addEventListener`

```
td.addEventListener("click", tdClick);
```

Comment: Thank you I tried that string approach earlier it works better, however it is till loading all of the json data from each entry. For example if I have 2 movies in the JSON object and when one title is clicked I want to display the rating any ONE click will display ALL of the ratings for both objects instead of the one specific to the click. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is a completely different question and would need more data shown as well as expected results